# Unity How can I use ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create an inventory system in Unity. I want to create an Item script that extends a Scriptable object. This script will hold specific values, and later, when the player interacts with objects in the game world, the properties of the object will be added to a list according to those values.

However, I have a question:
How can I recognize that a non-MonoBehaviour script belongs to a specific object in the game? And how can I understand that the object has properties defined by the Item script?

This is an exaple of my Item class:

```
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public string itemName;
    public int itemAmount;

    public Item(string itemName, int itemAmount)
    {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemAmount = itemAmount;
    }
}
```

What I want is for the player to acquire the properties of an object when they collide with it and add this information to a list:

```
public class ItemUse : MonoBehaviour
{
    Item item;
    public List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>();

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            item = new Item("erdem",2);
            ItemList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scriptable objects are more likely just simple data / template.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "items", menuName = "items/default")]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public int VNum;
    public string Name;
    public int Count;
}
```

"CreateAssetMenu" annotation will allow you to create file in project folder by right click (in empty space) and on the top "items" appears.

Set the properties in the inspector and attach this to your GameObject with "PickUpItem" script. (PickUpItem.cs is described later)

*What I want is for the player to acquire the properties of an object when they collide with it and add this information to a list:*

If I understand it correctly, your ItemUse.cs is your Inventory, so you will probably have to create another script called "PickUpItem", which will have that Item and OnTriggerEnter2D method with BoxCollider2D

PickUpItem.cs

```
[SerializeField]
Item Item;
[SerializeField]
int Count;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
      if(Invetory.Instance.AddItem(Item,Count)) {
         Destory(this.gameObject);
       }
    }
}
```

I would recommend to rename UseItem (if it's Inventory) to Inventory, create one static Instance (**learn about Singleton design pattern**) and add that function.

UseItem.cs ("Inventory.cs")

```
public bool AddItem(Item _item, int _count){
  var hasItem = ItemList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.itemName == _item.itemName);
  if(hasItem)  hasItem.Count += _count;
  else {
   var item_copy = Instantiate(_item) 
   item_copy.Count = _count;
   ItemList.Add(item_copy);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: instead of the singleton recommendation I would rather go the very opposite way around: The inventory is attached to the player => it can rather handle collisions with collectable items instead of the collectable items driving the behavior => `OnTriggerEnter2D` would rather only be on a component on the player which directly has access to the inventory ... the singleton approach would e.g. completely prevent splitscreen game plays ;)